# teradata collect stats using sample doesnt quite work

Tags: sql, database, database-design, teradata, table-statistics

trying to collect sample 2 pct multi column stats on a `VT`
Problem is , it does not sample or I am missing something

```
COLLECT STATISTICS USING sample 2 percent 
        COLUMN ( C1,C2,C3) , 
        COLUMN ( C1 ) on vt  ,
```

Volatile table VT has a few  Billion rows and it takes just as much "forever" time to collect stats on VT  as would be a regular stats collection.

 Also elsewhere , in a similar situation in past , I observed if I use the 'new'  ( many  cols  in one )  stats collection syntax , it'd sample the 1st col and ignore the rest  ( now this 2nd part isn't verified all the way since I based it more out of a 'time taken' hunch as against peeping into the histo. )

```
    show  stats values  
            COLUMN ( C1,C2,C3 ) , 
            COLUMN ( C1 )  on vt;

COLLECT STATISTICS 
            COLUMN ( C1,C2,C3 )
                ON  vt 
            VALUES
(
 /** SummaryInfo **/ 
 /* Data Type and Length: 'I8:8', 'I:4', 'CF:1' */
 /* TimeStamp             */ TIMESTAMP '2016-03-29 16:16:13-00:00', 
 /* Version               */ 6, 
 /* OriginalVersion       */ 6, 
 /* DBSVersion            */ '14.00.00', 
 /* UsageType             */ 'D', 
 /* ComplexStatInfo       */ 'ComplexStatInfo', 
 /* NumOfBiasedValues     */ 0, 
 /* NumOfEHIntervals      */ 200, 
 /* NumOfHistoryRecords   */ 1, 
 /* SamplePercent         */ 0.00, 
 /* NumOfNulls            */ 0, 
 /* NumOfAllNulls         */ 0, 
 /* NumOfPartialNullVals  */ 0, 
 /* PartialNullHMF        */ 0, 
 /* AvgAmpRPV             */ 0.000000, 
 /* MinVal                */ 2012070201942549261, 221945585, 'P', 
 /* MaxVal                */ 2014022922306867633, 277308727, 'P', 
 /* ModeVal               */ 2012070201942549261, 221945585, 'P', 
 /* HighModeFreq          */ 1, 
 /* NumOfDistinctVals     */ 1201056221, 
 /* NumOfRows             */ 1201056221, 
 /* CPUUsage              */ 0.000000, 
 /* IOUsage               */ 0.000000, 
 /* Reserved              */ 0, 
 /* Reserved              */ 0, 
 /* Reserved              */ 0.000000, 
 /* Reserved              */ 0.000000, 
 /* Reserved              */ '', 
 /* StatsSkipCount        */ 0, 
 /* SysInsertCnt          */ 0, 
 /* SysDeleteCnt          */ 0, 
 /* SysUpdateCnt          */ 0, 
 /* SysInsDelLastResetTS  */ TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 23:59:59-00:00', 
 /* SysUpdLastResetTS     */ TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 23:59:59-00:00', 
 /* IsSampleFollowingTrend*/ 0, 
 /** Interval: MaxVal[3], ModeVal[3], ModeFreq, LowFreq, OtherVals, OtherRows **/
```

here

`/* SamplePercent         */ 0.00,` 
 is what I am going by . I am sure I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this `/* DBSVersion            */ '14.00.00',` correct? You seem to run a very old release, is this a TD Express?

Well, if you got a 5,000,000,000 row table, this `/* NumOfRows             */ 1201056221,` seems to indicates approx. 25%, that's strange, too.

If you Explain your `COLLECT STATS` you can see if it's actually sampling or not.

Can you add the table's DDL?

Comment: Hi Dieter .TY .  I am so  sorry , I may sounded misleading with that 5 Billion-I kinda meant the  (*) is in billions ( like in conveying a huge table ) and hadn't paid attn to the specifics. Corrected the Q . I think this happened because I copied the VT with stats . Those were stale stats. So I may have to drop 'em to get the sampling to work ? I did explain the `collect stats` . It doesn't sound like it wanted to sample. So if there are Full stats existing on a VT , you can't sample on your 2nd run. For sampling to work - you have to throw full stats off ? TY again

Comment: @user1874594: Since TD14 the stats collection process remembers the SAMPLE setting, so when you collected once `USING SAMPLE 2 PERCENT` the next recollect will keep the sample even if you don't specify it. Simply run Explain.

Comment: @user1874594: I just tried it and it looks like `SAMPLE` doesn't work on Volatile Tables, don't know if this is documented (at least I didn't see it, yet). You better ask Carrie Ballinger on DevEx: http://developer.teradata.com/blog/carrie/2014/09/statistics-collection-recommendations-teradata-14-10-15-0-and-15-10

Comment: Updated Original Comment : TY..bummer on that .... So , how do I work around ? I think create VT from original table , putting`sample` filter to limit size - collect all the stats I want and then truncate table ( stats are preserved ) - followed by full insert ( is there a better way  to handle this ? ) . Problem is even after  I collect all stats that the optimizer wants  but with samples  not full stats - it will NOT change the explain plan. It still wants to continue doing those hash joins ( optimizer hooked on hash join hashish : ) ! ).    TY again for being responsive

Comment: Its asking for  combo stats and some are 99% skewed but I dont see any skewed row treatment in the explain. Also these are Medium confidence combo stats. After I collect samples- they do not disappear from the explain - still keep asking in the explain. So I wonder how much of stats ( esp sample ) collected from a VT are treated by the optimizer, seriously.

Comment: @user1874594: Regarding HELPSTATS requesting the same stats this seems to be known, see Carrie's comment:  http://developer.teradata.com/blog/carrie/2014/09/statistics-collection-recommendations-teradata-14-10-15-0-and-15-10#comment-144657